# If Spread Operator is not working in redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, spread-syntax

If Spread Operator (...) is not working in redux.
The spread operator is used for array construction and destructuring, and to fill function arguments from an array on invocation. A case when the operator spreads the array (or iterable object) elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open CMD
```

npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread

```
    and then create a file named .babelrc in your project directory, write the following code in it. Save and run npm.

    {
      "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
    }

Shared from https://github.com/kpilard
```